# Graylog container cannot connect to MongoDB container

Tags: mongodb, security, docker, graylog

I have some troubles setting up Graylog2 under docker. Everything works until I try using authentication. All I get is the following error repeated forever.

Trying both `root` and `graylog` user (in both `graylog` and `admin` db) gives the same result.

The log from mongodb says both users are created during setup. But graylog says it does not find any `graylog` user in database `graylog`. Same with user `root`.

I'm new to MongoDB and have no idea how authentication works. But from what I understand authentication (similar to `--auth` parameter) is activated when providing user/pw for root account (https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/pull/145).

Is it possible that Graylog ses a different authentication mechanism than MongoDB is excpecting? See line #158 in the [pasted log](https://pastebin.com/Zjxi5dxk)

**Error message as root user**

```
mongodb_1        | 2017-04-16T13:27:52.486+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] connection accepted from 172.18.0.4:46566 #12 (1 connection now open)
mongodb_1        | 2017-04-16T13:27:52.495+0000 I NETWORK  [conn12] received client metadata from 172.18.0.4:46566 conn12: { driver: { name: "mongo-java-driver", version: "unknown" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Linux", architecture: "amd64", version: "4.4.0-72-generic" }, platform: "Java/Oracle Corporation/1.8.0_72-internal-b15" }
mongodb_1        | 2017-04-16T13:27:52.525+0000 I ACCESS   [conn12] SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed for root on graylog from client 172.18.0.4:46566 ; UserNotFound: Could not find user root@graylog
mongodb_1        | 2017-04-16T13:27:52.543+0000 I -        [conn12] end connection 172.18.0.4:46566 (1 connection now open)
```

**Error message as graylog user** ([Full log on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Zjxi5dxk))

```
mongodb_1        | 2017-04-16T15:47:48.404+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] connection accepted from 172.18.0.4:41602 #7 (1 connection now open)
mongodb_1        | 2017-04-16T15:47:48.410+0000 I NETWORK  [conn7] received client metadata from 172.18.0.4:41602 conn7: { driver: { name: "mongo-java-driver", version: "unknown" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Linux", architecture: "amd64", version: "4.4.0-72-generic" }, platform: "Java/Oracle Corporation/1.8.0_72-internal-b15" }
mongodb_1        | 2017-04-16T15:47:48.418+0000 I ACCESS   [conn7] SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed for graylog on graylog from client 172.18.0.4:41602 ; UserNotFound: Could not find user graylog@graylog
mongodb_1        | 2017-04-16T15:47:48.423+0000 I -        [conn7] end connection 172.18.0.4:41602 (1 connection now open)
```

This is my **./docker-composer.yml**

```
    version: '2'
    services:
      mongodb:
        build: ./mongodb
        volumes:
          - /docker/mongodb/data:/data/db
      elasticsearch:
        image: "elasticsearch:2"
        command: "elasticsearch -Des.cluster.name='graylog'"
        volumes:
          - /docker/elasticsearch/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      graylog:
        image: graylog2/server
        volumes:
          - /docker/graylog/journal:/usr/share/graylog/data/journal
          - /docker/graylog/config:/usr/share/graylog/data/config
        environment:
          #GRAYLOG_MONGODB_URI: mongodb://root:drUqGGCMh@mongodb:27017/graylog
          GRAYLOG_MONGODB_URI: mongodb://graylog:vWGzncmBe9@mongodb:27017/graylog
        depends_on:
          - mongodb
          - elasticsearch
        ports:
          - "9000:9000"
```

**./mongodb/Dockerfile**

```
    FROM mongo:3
    ENV MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
    ENV MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: drUqGGCMh
    ADD grayloguser.js /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/grayloguser.js
```

**./mogodb/grayloguser.js**

```
    db.getSiblingDB('graylog');
    db.createUser(
      {
        user: "graylog",
        pwd: "vWGzncmBe9",
        roles: [
           { role: "dbOwner", db: "graylog" }
        ]
      }
    );
```

Comment: Looks like `UserNotFound: Could not find user root@graylog`. Do we have `root` user in `graylog` db ? Do you see the same error when you try to connect with `graylog` user ?

Comment: I get the excact error with the graylog user created with the JS script. Am I wrong thinking that dbOwner should be sufficient? I'm also thinking the root user with the role root according to the init script should be able to do everything?

Comment: I don't think role is a problem here for now. Looks like the users if created  are not being seen. How did you enable authorization ?  What kind of operation are you trying to do ?

Comment: The user is created, I can see that during the initial docker-compose and build, both the graylog user and root. However, when everything is up and graylog starts trying to connect and populate the DB it shows the errors above. I have made a pastebin with all the output. https://pastebin.com/ppyaWYzv

Comment: As far as i understand the authorization is enabled similar to the --auth parameter when the environment variables for user and password are given to the docker image and init process. https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/pull/145

Comment: Thank you for all the information. Logs look good and it looks like  `root` user is created in `admin` db  and application is looking in `graylog` db.  How is the application (mongo java driver) connection uri set up ? Is it set to look into admin db for root user ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your MongoDB script is incorrect.

Either assign the return value of [`db.getSiblingDB('graylog')`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getSiblingDB/) to a variable and use that for `createUser()`, or keep using `use graylog` instead:

```
graylog = db.getSiblingDB('graylog');
graylog.createUser(
  {
    user: "graylog",
    pwd: "vWGzncmBe9",
    roles: [
       { role: "dbOwner", db: "graylog" }
    ]
  }
);
```

In other words, just stick to the MongoDB documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/create-users/#username-password-authentication